# wso2 api manager 3.2.0 analytics redirect automatically to https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/oauth2_error

Tags: wso2-api-manager

why wso2 api manager 3.2.0 analytics redirect automatically from

```
https://172.24.64.115:9643/analytics-dashboard/
```

to

```
https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/oauth2_error.do?oauthErrorCode=invalid_callback&oauthErrorMsg=Registered+callback+does+not+match+with+the+provided+url.
```

Also following exception :
Registered callback does not match with the provided url Error

dashboard config :

```
## Authentication configuration
auth.configs:
  type: apim
  ssoEnabled: true
  properties:
    adminScope: apim_analytics:admin_carbon.super
    allScopes: apim_analytics:admin openid apim:api_view apim:subscribe apim_analytics:monitoring_dashboard:own apim_analytics:monitoring_dashboard:edit apim_analytics:monitoring_dashboard:view apim_analytics:business_analytics:own apim_analytics:business_analytics:edit apim_analytics:business_analytics:view apim_analytics:api_analytics:own apim_analytics:api_analytics:edit apim_analytics:api_analytics:view apim_analytics:application_analytics:own apim_analytics:application_analytics:edit apim_analytics:application_analytics:view
    adminUsername: admin
    adminPassword: admin
    kmDcrUrl: https://172.24.64.114:9443/client-registration/v0.17/register
    kmTokenUrlForRedirection: https://172.24.64.114:9443/oauth2
    kmTokenUrl: https://172.24.64.114:9443/oauth2
    kmUsername: admin
    kmPassword: admin
    portalAppContext: analytics-dashboard
    businessRulesAppContext : business-rules
    cacheTimeout: 30
    baseUrl: https://172.24.64.115:9643
    grantType: authorization_code
    publisherUrl: https://172.24.64.114:9443
    devPortalUrl: https://172.24.64.114:9443
    externalLogoutUrl: https://172.24.64.114:9443/oidc/logout
```

Comment: The Analytics Dashboard uses the SSO with API Manager to provide access to the Widgets. Can you try using the Incognito mode and accessing the `/analytics-dashboard` endpoint?

Comment: Also, at the same time, log-in to the API Manager server's Carbon console (with admin credentials), and go to Service Providers > List > `sp_analytics_dashboard` > `OAuth2/OpenID Configurations` > Edit and check the Callback URL configured. Whether the Hostnames are correct or not and aligning to the `baseUrl` configured in the `deployment.yaml` of the Dashboard.

Comment: Yes that's exactlly true. really thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below-mentioned error can happen when the Hostname configured under the `baseUrl` of the Analytics Dashboard's `deployment.yaml` is not matching with the Callback URL configured in the API Manager node.

```
https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/oauth2_error.do?oauthErrorCode=invalid_callback&oauthErrorMsg=Registered+callback+does+not+match+with+the+provided+url.
```

Perform the following checks and update the Callback URL accordingly to overcome the behavior

- Log-in to the API Manager's Carbon Management console with Admin credentials
- Go to `Service Providers` > List > `sp_analytics_dashboard` and expand the `OAuth2/OpenID Configurations` and click on `Edit`
- Verify whether the configured Callback URLs are matching with the Hostname and port defined in `baseUrl` in the `deployment.yaml` of the Analytics Dashboard. If not, update them.

Once after updating, save the configurations and try the scenario.

Comment: Just, after config carbon, to apply config on analytics , server should be restarted.